# How to save sent items mail using the Java mail API?

Tags: java

How do I save sent items in mail using the Javamail API?

```
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props,new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthenticationgetPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication("user id","pwd");
    }
});

Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setHeader("X-Priority","1");
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("user id"));
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(Toaddress));

message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC,InternetAddress.parse(cc));
message.setSubject("Subject");
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart.setText("test mail");
Transport.send(message);
```

Comment: What seems to be your problem?

Comment: @APerson241 i want to save the sent mail to my local drive.when the mail was sent.

Comment: Use data base to store your mail detail after sending mail

Comment: @Manish k thanks...is it possible to send mail via the outlook express using java?

Comment: check in your gmail sent items

Comment: before sending the mail , store the mail content in some variable , then after sending the mail simply store the mail content in to some file or database , and create the saved mail in any template you ever want

Comment: @vels4j i want the sent mail in my local drive.dont go to gmail sent item.

Comment: @ Hussain Akhtar Wahid thanks i got idea from u r valid information..

Comment: @user1990589 your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

With Gmail you don't need to save it in the sent folder, Gmail does that automatically for you

Comment: ya,i dont mean that. I want to store the sent mail in my local drive like Ms outlook.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution

```
/*
 *  This is the code for read the sent mails from your mail account.
 *  Requirements:
 *      JDK 1.5 and above
 *      Jar:mail.jar
 *
 */

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.Flags.Flag;
import javax.mail.search.FlagTerm;

public class ReadSentMail
{
 Folder sent;

 //Constructor of the class.
 public ReadSentMail()
 {
 /*  Set the mail properties  */
 Properties props = System.getProperties();
 props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
 try
 {
 /*  Create the session and get the store for read the mail. */
 Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
 Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
 store.connect("imap.gmail.com","<email-id>", "<password>");

 /*  Mention the folder name which you want to read. */
 sent = store.getFolder("[Gmail]/Sent Mail");
 System.out.println("No of Sent Messages : " +sent.getMessageCount());

 /*Open the inbox using store.*/
 sent.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

 /*  Get the messages which is unread in the Sent Mails*/
 Message messages[] = sent.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flag.SEEN), true));

 /* Use a suitable FetchProfile    */
 FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
 fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
 fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.CONTENT_INFO);
 sent.fetch(messages, fp);

 try
 {
 printAllMessages(messages);
 sent.close(true);
 store.close();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 System.out.println("Exception arise at the time of read mail");
 ex.printStackTrace();
 }
 }
 catch (NoSuchProviderException e)
 {
 e.printStackTrace();
 System.exit(1);
 }
 catch (MessagingException e)
 {
 e.printStackTrace();
 System.exit(2);
 }
 }

 public void printAllMessages(Message[] msgs) throws Exception
 {
 for (int i = msgs.length-1; i > 0; i--)
 {
 System.out.println("MESSAGE #" + (i + 1) + ":");
 printEnvelope(msgs[i]);
 }
 }

 /*  Print the envelope(FromAddress,ReceivedDate,Subject)  */
 public void printEnvelope(Message message) throws Exception
 {
 Address[] a;
 // FROM
 if ((a = message.getFrom()) != null)
 {
 for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
 {
 System.out.println("FROM: " + a[j].toString());
 }
 }
 // TO
 if ((a = message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO)) != null)
 {
 for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
 {
 System.out.println("TO: " + a[j].toString());
 }
 }
 String subject = message.getSubject();
 Date receivedDate = message.getReceivedDate();
 String content = message.getContent().toString();
 System.out.println("Subject : " + subject);
 System.out.println("Received Date : " + receivedDate.toString());
 System.out.println("Content : " + content);
 getContent(message);
 }

 public void getContent(Message msg)
 {
 try
 {
 String contentType = msg.getContentType();
 System.out.println("Content Type : " + contentType);
 Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
 int count = mp.getCount();
 for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
 {
     readMessageToFile(mp.getBodyPart(i));
 }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 System.out.println("Exception arise at get Content");
 ex.printStackTrace();
 }
 }

 public void readMessageToFile(Part p) throws Exception
 {
 // Dump input stream ..
 InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
 // If "is" is not already buffered, wrap a BufferedInputStream
 // around it.
 if (!(is instanceof BufferedInputStream))
 {
 is = new BufferedInputStream(is);
 }
 int c;
 System.out.println("Message : ");
 while ((c = is.read()) != -1)
 {
 System.out.write(c);
 }
 }

 public static void main(String args[])
 {
 new ReadSentMail();
 }
```